System freeze after Try or Install wellcome screen in HP Pavillion x360
I have an HP Pavillion x360 notebook in which I installed a brand new empty SSD, and trying to install Ubuntu from a USB stick. I tried with 20.04 and 22.04 versions, booting in safe graphics mode. In both cases, the Welcome screen appears, but when I click on Try Ubuntu or on Install Ubuntu, the system freezes and nothing happens (although I can move the mouse pointer). The only option left is a hard reset (turn off the computer). I also tried to install 24.04, but in this case it freezes after loading plymouthd. Any ideas?

After several days of trial an error, I finally found the solution, thanks to this article.
The freezing during installation occurs because the Linux kernel appears to have issues with HP hardware, and stays reporting lots of PCI Bus errors.
The solution is to boot the kernel with the option pci=noaer and after that the installation runs smoothly.
To do this, I booted from the Live CD and at the GRUB screen, I press the key e to edit the options of the 'Try or Install Ubuntu' menu. I added the pci=noaer option after the quiet splash options, and press Ctrl+x to save and proceed to boot.
Of course after the installation, it is necessary to include the same kernel option in the installed GRUB. To modify the installed GRUB from the Live CD, I followed this recipe
